# How can I check if a user is in a Telegram group? I get a reply that he is out

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf.js

I use the NodeJS Telegraf package to program my Telegram bot.
I'm trying to check if the user is in the channel using the following code:

```js
 const channelLeft = await ctx.telegram.getChatMember("@dji_fly_app_hebrew",ctx.message.from.id);
console.log(channelLeft.status)
```

And I always receive in the status that it is outside... ("left")
Even if the user inside the channel...
The bot has all access to the channel.

Comment: Hey @orielhaim, I am looking for the same thing.
As far as I've understood it is not possible but did you manage to pull it off?
Thanks and regards